# Reverse proxy and auto_complete with mixed content

Tags: proxies

I have an apache configuration with reverse proxy (IP of this server: `192.168.1.82`) to handle my new D9 server:

**192.168.1.82 :** 443 is passed to 192.168.1.87 as HTTP(80)

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mydomain.be
    ServerAlias mydomain.be
    NameVirtualHost www.mydomain.be

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.87:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.87/
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
    SSLProxyVerify none
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I think it is called SSL Termination

**192.168.1.82 :** 80 is redirected as https (443)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.be
    Redirect permanent / https://www.mydomain.be/
</VirtualHost>
```

**192.168.1.87 :** settings.php

```
$settings['reverse_proxy'] = TRUE;
$settings['reverse_proxy_addresses'] = [
  '192.168.1.82',
];
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$settings['ssl'] = TRUE;
```

Unfortunately the autocomplete feature of an entity reference field request a non https (unsecure) endpoint (Mixed content):

```
http://www.mydomain.be/fr/entity_reference_autocomplete/node/default:node/3veI...I?q=t
```

What can I do to force the https... I will accept the most ugly hack if it is working (yes, I am here)

**Test 1**: ProxyPass https instead of http [will not work, see below]

I have adapted the 82 virtual host as follow;

```
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass / https://192.168.1.87/
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.87/
```

=>This time I don't have the mixed content problem, but I have `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` again for this entity autocomplete endpoint

**Test 2**: hack Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::isSecure()

Here is my new isSecure() function:

```
public function isSecure(){
  return TRUE;
}
```

By doing this, the autocomplete url use https, but this time, I got `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

```
GET https://www.mydomain.be/fr/entity_reference_autocomplete/node/default%3Anode/3ve...I?q=T net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I have really no clue from where it can come

Comment: Have you tried enforcing this at the htaccess level?

Comment: good idea: how to do it? Many thank by advance for the tip!!!

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/

Comment: @kevin: this is not an https redirection, this is a SSL termination: 82 is handling encryption and it pass the result (ProxyPass) to 87 as plain http. My setup looks nearly good as everything works execpt the mixed content. I don't know if this is a Drupal problem or an Apache problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to set X-Forwarded-* headers in the Apache reverse proxy:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mydomain.be
    ServerAlias mydomain.be
    NameVirtualHost www.mydomain.be

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.87:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.87/

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

These are the headers which the reverse proxy configuration in settings.php needs.

You can check the presence of the headers at *[www.mydomain.be/admin/reports/status/php](http://www.mydomain.be/admin/reports/status/php)* in the section **HTTP Headers Information**

---

In such a setup using X-Forward-* headers is the general approach to allow Drupal to build absolute links with the correct protocol to avoid the mixed content error.

However, Drupal pages can be built completely with relative links and this is how Drupal is setup out-of-the-box, including core autocomplete fields. So you could review autocomplete routes in contrib/custom code and remove the `absolute` option to make them relative.

---

**Redirecting**

To avoid further commenting, Drupal doesn't redirect, out-of-the-box. Redirecting is not connected to the issue, it only makes it harder to debug. It's impossible to tell from afar which code you might have implemented which is redirecting. It could also be that the redirects are still cached, permanent redirects get cached for weeks, even if you have removed the redirect code.

Comment: Looks very good!!! I will test this this evening... I can't wait

Comment: OK, when testing check the phpinfo() output of your Drupal site before and after the change. See the edit.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working (info: header are set in status page)=> I got `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` for the autocomplete. There is also the `X-Forwarded-For` which is set to `192.168.1.1`, don't know if this is what it should be

Comment: This is the client IP, you need this, too. Apache sets this header by default. But what did happen with the two I've suggested? Missing before and present after? Then remove any other hacks, clear all caches, also the browser cache, restart all servers and try again.

Comment: `X-Forwarded-Proto` is set to `https` and `X-Forwarded-Port` is set to 443 as displayed by `phpinfo()`.

Comment: do you know a way to trace the "too many" redirects? Is-it an Apache stuff or could it be a Drupal problem?

Comment: There are too many redirects in this topic.  You don't need any to debug the mixed content issue, you can connect the browser with the proxy over https by typing it in the address bar. Debug the http->https redirect on the edge proxy when anything else is working and then start with non-permanent 302s.

Comment: I have read 10 times your last comment, but I do not get it... it is completely cryptic for me. Would you mind to write down your idea in your answer? All my Apache configuration is here in the post, there is no other redirect than the one which is redirecting http to https. I don't know what is an "Edge proxy"

Comment: To be clear, you need to remove any redirect code and start over. Permanent redirects are very hard to debug (the most annoying thing I know). Later (not connected with the issue) you can add a redirect to the reverse proxy (the proxy on the edge to the client) to change http to https in the addressbar automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I will remove the permanent redirect this evening (this is a test site which is live now... I could make it work by changing the port number and by redirecting the traffic [using this port] to my 87 server with my firewall... people agree to use another port for a test site) but I can work on it only in the evening...

Comment: I have removed ALL the config from the edge server except the proxy one described at the begining of this question. I have replaced the .htaccess by the original ones and I still get the too many redirect. How to know from where it is coming?

Comment: Thanks so much @4uk4! I was debugging a Symfony application in a similar setup to this question and for some reason `RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"` is the thing that was missing from my request, resulting in an infinite redirect between Symfony and Apache.

Answer (score 1):

The htaccess file in Drupal should be able to force all traffic as HTTPS. There are some comments in the file, but something like this should work (used in several projects):

```
  # Force all traffic to HTTPS, except a local instance
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local\.dev\.domain$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]




  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /
```

The third line is optional - it would exempt a local dev environment from the rewrite. If you use a local SSL, you can omit that line.

If Apache is serving all requests, it will pass through these rules, evaluate them and do the rewrite.

You can test rules here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/

Here is the test: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=69ce1303-b1af-4041-aecf-a32f2ecd1bfb

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I have added the 4 lines at the end of default drupal file without success: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=1cbb4094-19ed-4407-96a3-07c50a159c68

Comment: The order matters in htaccess. Try it after this comment line `# RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: I updated my answer so you can see where the rules should go. See new results: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=e8e28846-517d-42cf-bc84-d46a736bdd62

Comment: Unfortunatly, I got ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: This is because https is forwarded to server 87 as http by my apache server 82... my apache 87 is handling onlt port 80

Comment: I have added more details in my question